# Demandware server eclipse

Tags: eclipse, salesforce, commerce, demandware

I uploaded cartridges to the demandware server on eclipse and after I did that it looks like my sandbox isn't uploading the css file. Is there a way to revert back? Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you clarify what you did and what is happening? The sandbox doesn't "upload" anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, unfortunatly you can't.

The only thing you can do is to activate another code version in the business manager or to fix the problem.